# Top Results based on stastics in SOLR

Tags: solr, grouping, faceted-search

I am working with SOLR 3.6.I have list of users and the data they have downloaded from internet in bytes..i have applied facets on it.now i want that based on the top download of bytes by users the result should be displayed.

i have research through result group(FieldCollapsing) in that score field.but it didnt worked for me..as i want the user_name should also be grouped.i have used below query:but it didnt worked

```
http://localhost:8085/solr/select?q=iap:1&stats=true&stats.field=recv_bytes&stats.twopass=true&rows=0&indent=true&stats.facet=user_name&stats.sort=count(recv_byets)
```

first,  i was using this..this was giving me grouped result.but not with the statistics..so i have used the above query..

```
http://localhost:8085/solr/select?wt=json&indent=true&fl=id,category,log_component,user_name,w_date&q=iap:1&group=true&group.field=user_name
```

For SQL Database my query will form like this..

```
select USERNAME,SUM(RECV_BYTES) as BYTES from WEB_USER_5MIN where "5mintime" >=timestamp '2012-07-02 00:00:00' and "5mintime" <= timestamp '2012-07-02 23:59:59' and APPID in ('64.11.122.0cyberoam') group by username order by bytes desc
```

so mainly for ORDER BY BYTES DESC i want the appropriate solr to work..

Comment: Sorrybut I think you should clarify a little your question, maybe adding an example. Where do you use grouping in your url?

Comment: I want the result based on the user_name like so..i have query like this..select USERNAME,SUM(HITS) as HITS,SUM(BYTES) as BYTES from WEB_USER_5MIN
where "5mintime" >=timestamp '2012-07-02 00:00:00' and "5mintime" <= timestamp '2012-07-02 23:59:59' and APPID in ('64.11.122.0cyberoam') group by username order by hits desc ...so for that i am using SOLR as stats.facet=user_name after applying facets and stats i want the sorting based on sum(bytes)..